# Cleaning after installation

Tags: make, configure

Is it safe to remove the downloaded tar once the program is installed (once I run ./configure, make, make install)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, and no.

Removing source file won't affect installed binaries and other resources,

But you should keep them, in case you need to rebuild them. i.e when system libraries updated, it's likely for you to rebuild / re-link the binary

Comment: So when you rebuild everything is overwritten?

Comment: @saadtaame yes you can override the installed binaries, provided the `--prefix` is the same value (Which controls the installation prefix)

Comment: If `make uninstall` is supported, that's another (minor) reason. Given the typical convoluted autoconf generated `Makefile`, it's not usually trivial to work out which bits you need for that.

Comment: http://asic-linux.com.mx/~izto/checkinstall/ is a useful tool for generating a package, allowing you to uninstall more easily at a later time.

Answer (score 0):

Also, sometimes packages install stuff in directories called by the version. It is wise to keep the sources around to be able to find out what was installed to clean up later.

But probably the best course of action is to create a proper package for your system, and install that. The package management system will then keep care of dependencies, and handle updates. Yes, creating the package means tracking down the dependencies and other data, but that is something that has to be done anyway sooner or later.